# SwipeRefreshLayout/ListFragment Loading style issues

Tags: android, android-styles, swiperefreshlayout

I learned from Android SDK sample [SwipeRefreshListFragment](http://developer.android.com/samples/SwipeRefreshListFragment/index.html)

and tried SwipeRefreshLayout/ListFragment in new test app by using support-v4

I found a difference:
in offical sample, SwipeRefreshListFragment Loading style is a rotating circle, but in my test app, loading style is a colorful line on top of the fragment

i tried to change gradle config both minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 21 (set to 14 before), but still the old style.

Is there any version config caused this diff?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
android { 
       compileSdkVersion 21 
       buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
       defaultConfig { 
            applicationId "com.weibo.biz.tongji" 
            minSdkVersion 21 targetSdkVersion 21 
      } buildTypes { 
        release { 
          minifyEnabled false proguardFiles         
          getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
       } 
    } 
} 
dependencies { 
      compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar') 
      compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.11' 
}
```

Comment: it is in the latest support library. Which one are you using?

Comment: here's some gif example  [my test app](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20150127122143546) , [offical style](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20150127120706062)

Comment: can you post your build.gradle?

Comment: I just copied support-v4.jar from offical SwipeRefreshListFragment lib directory. and md5 has the same digest.

Comment: @Blackbelt comment has char limits, Here's pasterbin for build.gradle http://pastebin.com/1ZavG4qF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

```
 compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

and add

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

and you should get the rounded style